# Projection LINQ return null reference exception on navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to move a LINQ projection to an extension method, but I am getting a null ref exception, even if I use Include on my navigation property.
If I maintain the projection on the service, the query works just fine.

```
 public class Order {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  //...

  //nav
  public User User { get; set; } 
  public Cliente Cliente { get;  set; }  
}

IQueryable<Orders> baseQuery = _ctx.Orders
            .Include(i => i.User)
            .Include(i => i.Cliente)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .IgnoreQueryFilters()
            .OrderBy($"{orderby} {direction}");

            IQueryable<OrderViewModel> queryLinq = baseQuery
            .Where(x =>
                  //some filter
              )
              .Select(order => new OrderViewModel
              {
                  Id= order.Id,
                  UserName = order.User.UserName,
                  Ragsoc = order.Customer.Name,
              });
```

If I move it to an extension e.g.

```cs
.Select (order => order.ToOrderViewModel()
```

It will throw me an null ref exception. What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: If you remove the Where do you get results?

Comment: i try but nothing

Comment: Is baseQuery null?

Comment: baseQuery have data

Comment: in the first code, `order` parameter is not used. `Order` is used instead

Comment: What line in `ToOrderViewModel` is throwing the null reference exception? Presumably, either `Order.User` or `Order.Customer` is an optional relationship, so either `UserName` or `Ragsoc` become `null` when EF projects, but your code doesn't know about that.

Comment: Exact all nav prop return null ref exception. I want use extension method for performance and maintainable reason...i cant figoure out